# How to cancel a future action if another future did failed?

Tags: scala, playframework, future, for-comprehension, concurrent-processing

I have 2 futures (2 actions on db tables) and I want that before saving modifications to check if both futures have finished successfully.

Right now, I start second future inside the first (as a dependency), but I know is not the best option. I know I can use a `for`-comprehension to execute both futures in parallel, but even if one fail, the other will be executed (not tested yet)

```
firstFuture.dropColumn(tableName) match {
  case Success(_) => secondFuture.deleteEntity(entity)
  case Failure(e) => throw new Exception(e.getMessage)
}

// the  first future alters a table, drops a column
// the second future deletes a row from another table
```

in this case, if first future is executed successfully, the second can fail. I want to revert the update of first future. I heard about SQL transactions, seems to be something like that, but how?

```
val futuresResult = for {
  first <- firstFuture.dropColumn(tableName)
  second <- secondFuture.deleteEntity(entity)
} yield (first, second)
```

A `for`-comprehension is much better in my case because I don't have dependencies between these two futures and can be executed in parallel, but this not solve my problem, the result can be (success, success) or (failed, success) for example.

Comment: Futures are not cancellable. And a for-comprehension uses map / flatMap, which means Futures are still run in sequence, not paralllel. You really should use transactions; but how to do that depends on the library you're using... (currently it seems like your methods are returning `Try[T]` and not `Future`?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Regarding `Future` running sequentially vs in parallel:

This is a bit tricky because Scala `Future` is designed to be **eager**. There are some other constructs across various Scala libraries that handle synchronous and asynchronous effects, such as cats `IO`, Monix `Task`, `ZIO` etc. which are designed in a **lazy** way, and they don't have this behaviour.

The thing with `Future` being eager is that it will start the computation as soon as it is can. Here "start" means schedule it on an `ExecutionContext` that is either selected explicitly or present implicitly. While it's technically possible that the execution is stalled a bit in case the scheduler decides to do so, it will most likely be started almost instantaneously.

So if you have a value of type `Future`, it's going to start running then and there. If you have a lazy value of type `Future`, or a function / method that returns a value of type `Future`, then it's not.

But even if all you have are simple values (no lazy vals or defs), if the `Future` definition is done inside the for-comprehension, then it means it's part of a monadic flatMap chain (if you don't understand this, ignore it for now) and it will be run *in sequence*, not in parallel. Why? This is not specific to `Future`s; every for-comprehension has the semantics of being a sequential chain in which you can pass the result of the previous step to the next step. So it's only logical that you can't run something in step *n + 1* if it depends on something from step *n*.

Here's some code to demonstrate this.

```
val program = for {
  _ <- Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println("f1") }
  _ <- Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println("f2") }
} yield ()

Await.result(program, Duration.Inf)
```

This program will wait five seconds, then print "f1", then wait another five seconds, and then print "f2".

Now let's take a look at this:

```
val f1 = Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println("f1") }
val f2 = Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println("f2") }

val program = for {
  _ <- f1
  _ <- f2
} yield ()

Await.result(program, Duration.Inf)
```

The program, however, will print "f1" and "f2" simultaneously after five seconds.

Note that the sequence semantics are not really violated in the second case. `f2` still has the opportunity to use the result of `f1`. But `f2` is not using the result of `f1`; it's a standalone value that can be computed immediately (defined with a `val`). So if we change `val f2` to a function, e.g. `def f2(number: Int)`, then the execution changes:

```
val f1 = Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println("f1"); 42 }
def f2(number: Int) = Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println(number) }

val program = for {
  number <- f1
  _ <- f2(number)
} yield ()
```

As you would expect, this will print "f1" after five seconds, and only then will the other `Future` start, so it will print "42" after another five seconds.

### Regarding transactions:

As @cbley mentioned in the comment, this sounds like you want database transactions. For example, in SQL databases this has a very [specific meaning](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm) and it ensures the [ACID properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

If that's what you need, you need to solve it on the database layer. `Future` is too generic for that; it's just an effect type that models sync and async computations. When you see a `Future` value, just by looking at the type, you can't tell if it's the result of a database call or, say, some HTTP call.

For example, [doobie](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/) describes every database query as a `ConnectionIO` type. You can have multiple queries lined up in a for-comprehension, just how you would have with `Future`:

```
val program = for {
  a <- database.getA()
  _ <- database.write("foo")
  b <- database.getB()
} yield {
  // use a and b
}
```

But unlike our earlier examples, here `getA()` and `getB()` don't return a value of type `Future[A]`, but `ConnectionIO[A]`. What's cool about that is that doobie completely takes care of the fact that you probably want these queries to be run in a single transaction, so if `getB()` fails, "foo" will not be committed to the database.

So what you would do in that case is obtain the full description of your set of queries, wrap it into a single value `program` of type `ConnectionIO`, and once you want to actually run the transaction, you would do something like `program.transact(myTransactor)`, where `myTransactor` is an instance of `Transactor`, a [doobie construct](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/14-Managing-Connections.html#about-transactors) that knows how to connect to your physical database.

And once you transact, your `ConnectionIO[A]` is turned into a `Future[A]`. If the transaction failed, you'll have a failed `Future`, and nothing will be really committed to your database.

If your database operations are independent of each other and can be run in parallel, doobie will also allow you to do that. Committing transactions via doobie, both in sequence and in parallel, is quite nicely explained [in the docs](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/03-Connecting.html#our-third-program).